# In VS Code, Flutter language classes and widgets are not colored for me, but some words are blue

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, Flutter language classes and widgets are not colored for me, but some words are blue .
The `Flutter` and `Dart` plugins are installed and flutter doctor run without any problem.
Please look at this:
[image]

Comment: It's not a Flutter related issue. Check if you don't have any plugin that will generate this unwanted behaviour like prettier for example

Comment: Sometimes the VS Code extensions flake out and you have to restart the IDE for coloring to fix itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `Settings` (`Cmd+,` on Mac), and search for `theme color`. You will find a `Workbench: Color Theme` setting. Here select `Dark+` or `Light+` and that should help.

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you don't want to use the `Dark+` or `Light+` themes (as a matter of taste e.g., I personally prefer the `Visual Studio Dark - C++` theme) is to add the following to your `settings.json`:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": ["support.class.dart"],
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#4EC9B0" // the C++ theme class color
            }
        }
    ]
},
```